# How to make content background white

Tags: html, css, background

I am new to programming and have a basic question.  I have a background image on my web page, but I want the content area to have a white background.  I see this very commonly on the web but being new I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.  I have a #wrapper div that centers my content and a css rule to show the image, just can't get the content area background to be white.  Help for this newbie is appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to show us your code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: in your div attributes area (or in the CSS applied to a selector of it) style="background-color:white;"

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this. You can either set the styles of your HTML tags (`div`, `span`, `p` etc...) by using the `style` attribute as in the example:

```
<div style="background-color: white;"></div>
```

or either define your styles inside the `<head></head>` tag as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
             .your_class { background-color: #ffffff; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="your_class"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

or either use the `link` tag to put your CSS code inside a file and link to it as:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_file.css">
</head>
```

Or sometimes you will need to set your style dynamically. Then javascript enters into the picture:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function changeBg(id, color) {
                document.getElementById(id).style.bgColor = color;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="changeBg('myDiv', 'white');">
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should read more on HTML and CSS to understand how it works. There are plenty of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a structure like this :

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section id="content">            <!-- Or div or whatever -->
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

You should apply a `background-color` to `#wrapper` :

```
body{
   background-image: url("your_url");
}

#wrapper{
   background-color:white;
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/agEtL/) for a working example.

Comment: How easy could it be?!  Totally worked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MicheleHermes You're welcome! Please accept my answer, for future visitor to see that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put your content inside a div and specify `background:#fff;` for that div in your CSS.